# Dovecot error reading mailbox: Can't expand ~/ for mail root

Tags: mysql, dovecot

I want to configure dovecot to use mysql as users database.
This is my config:

```
# Authentication for SQL users. Included from 10-auth.conf.
#
# <doc/wiki/AuthDatabase.SQL.txt>

passdb {
  driver = sql

  # Path for SQL configuration file, see example-config/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}

# "prefetch" user database means that the passdb already provided the
# needed information and there's no need to do a separate userdb lookup.
# <doc/wiki/UserDatabase.Prefetch.txt>
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
```

Dovecot has mail_gid and mail_uid set to mail user (exim user).
And this is the sql config:

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock dbname=system user=dovecot password=mypass
default_pass_scheme = PLAIN
password_query = SELECT password, '/var/mail/%d/%n' AS userdb_home FROM user WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d'
```

And this is the error after a good login:

```
dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<test@user>, method=PLAIN, rip=xxx, lip=xxx, mpid=24372, session=<dwTdGT8n0QBf9La9>
dovecot: pop3(test@user): Error: user test@user: Initialization failed: Namespace '': Home directory not set for user. Can't expand ~/ for mail root dir in: ~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/domain/test@user
dovecot: pop3(test@user): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

I check the mysql log and I found a correct reply with the password and home.
What can it be? May I add dovecot user to mail group?

Answer (score 1):

There was two errors:

- Exim mail format did not match with dovecot mail format, exim was using **maildir**, dovecot was configured with **mbox**. I had to change dovecot configuration to maildir.
- Dovecot maildir configuration used full address as user folder, exim wrote its user folder only with user part of the address. Example: **/var/mail/mydomain.com/myuser@mydomain.com** instead of **/var/mail/mydomain.com/myuser**

I had to change this configuration row in dovecot
From:

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%d/%u
```

to

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n
```

(I underline the "maildir" prefix instead of "mbox" and the %n placeholder instead of %u)